# Find the value of a which form the equation

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$a$ is an odd number and the value of $a$ could be between $1$ and $39$.

Find the value of $a$ which means the equation:

$$x^2 +2xyz +y^2 =a$$

has integer roots

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by a "root" of an equation in three variables, $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: If $\;a=1\;$, for example, then $\;(\pm1,0)\,,\,\,(0,\pm1)\;$ are solutions; if $\;a=9\;$, then $\;(\pm3,0),\,\,(0,\pm3)\;$ are, etc. What do you mean with " find the value of $\;a\;$ "? There are several, as the above shows...

Comment: a=(1,9,17,25,33)

Comment: @GerryMyerspn It was translated from my native language so I might confused. But it means that all the variables (x,y,z) could change by the time a is changed , all of them have different roots. I guess !

Comment: #DonAntonio there are 3 variables ! So they want us to find the value of a which make the X,Y,Z have the possible roots. And their roots are integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words find all values $a$ which are attainable by function $f=x^2+2xyz+y^2$ if $x,y,z$ are integers.
Take $x=y=1$ then $f=2z+2$ and so all even numbers are  attainable.
Take $x=1, y=2$  then $f=4z+5$ and so all the integers congruent to $1\pmod{4}$ are attainable.
Show that the rest integers are not attainable. As they are odd then only one of $x$ and $y$ must be odd. But in this case we would have $f\equiv 1\pmod {4}.$
In a given range only 10 numbers $3,7,\ldots, 39$ are not attainable.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am wondering why we choose mod 4  and not mod 12 or mod 24 ..? Because it is the smallest possible devider ?

Comment: Because 4 itself turned out: $f=4z+5=4(z+1)+1$

Comment: Okay I understand clearly now. Thank you so much.